# How to change Skype port in windows 8.1?

Tags: skype

how to change skype port in windows 8.1? Apache/xampp is not running even after changing default value of httpd.conf and httpd-ssl.conf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modern Skype app uses port 80 by default. There is no option to change the port settings. Port 80 must be forwarded for modern Skype app to operate properly.

Please See this thread.
http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-8-1-from-Windows-Store/No-proxy-settings-option-in-Windows-8-Skype/m-p/1155558/highlight/true#M299

Answer (score 3):

Uninstall the Windows 8 "app" version of Skype, and download the desktop version from the Skype website (at the time of writing, this can be found at http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-windows/downloading/ ).

You can then go to `Tools | Options... | Advanced | Connection` as normal.

Comment: Its the metro version of skype that causes that problem u r right. When I uninstalled it, I didnt have any more problems